Repairing shower tile, water damage, loose tiles, possibly poor installation
Background: I have a few loose tiles in my shower.  I intended to just pull and replace them with new thin-set and grout.  After pulling them out I realized that the damage might be more significant than I first thought.  In pics 2, 3, and 4 you can see the damage more clearly and that whatever the backer is can be scraped clean.  You can also see an approx 1/4" lip where the backer board extends beyond the lip of the shower pan.  No adhesive stuck to the tiles on the bottom half.  Pic 5 is the left/back of the shower.  Pic 6 is the right/front of the shower. There are maybe 3-4 more loose tiles to pull.  The bathroom will be remodled in a few years so I am hoping for an easy temporary solution.  Family is visiting in 10 days and we would like both showers operational.
Can I continue with the pull and replace if I clean the backer board?
How do I deal with the lip over the shower pan?
How do I know if it's greenboard or drywall?  This determines the type of adhesive right?
What else do I need to be thinking about?
Thank you all so much for the help!







Everywhere you see grout missing is a possible leak point.   Any way to see under that shower area?

Sadly no. We know there is some minimal water damage to the ceiling below. Just did a total reno on the other bathroom which had more water damage leaking through. Didn’t require mitigation.

Sorry, but your shower walls should be torn out and rebuilt with updated materials. Durock or Schluter Kerdi over the studs. Proper waterproofing and new tile and grout. (It would not make sense here to post each step.)
A shower can be rebuilt in 10 days or less. The problem is scheduling. If you prefer to tackle it yourself, look at alot of videos.
An unknown is whether or not any structural wood has been damaged. You will not know that until the walls are down.
I know this info sucks, but trying to cobble a paste together solution will only result in more damage, especially when company uses the shower more often.
In some areas there are "One day shower remodeling" companies. You could try that. Some offer financing.

Agreed with the answer, esp about timing. I am in the middle of a similar shower remodel. Actual time working? The equivalent of 3 days, max. Actual calendar days to do the project? Two months, minimum. Around here it takes at least a month to schedule a plumber, and then you have the inspections

I just tiled a full shower. Actual working time? Probably about 3 days (considering I'm very amateur), total working time from start to finish, several months (things like job & chemo kinda get in the way).

@FreeMan  Sorry about the chemo.

@Freeman, So you are dealing with chemo AND tiling a shower!  That sir is some studly work.
